# UIScrollView showing nil?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uibutton

i have one sample project with UIPageViewController. In my first page(of pageviewcontroller :   class name- step1Controller) there is one "Continue button. When i click on that button i need to scroll the first page and show second page (instead of swipe here click on button will change page).

So on button click i called method to do auto scroll and un fortunatly it showing my uiscrollview frame is nil.??  how do i fix this ??please help

I have attached copy of project (its a small file 200kb)

My code structure is like

```
ViewController (click on "add" button open second viewcontroller)-->MainController (here i have uiscrollview and uipageviewcontroller connected to 6 pages).

When  i click "Continue" green button from first page it should auto scroll and sho the second page.
```

Please help.

```
Code on first page of pageview

- (IBAction)continueButton:(id)sender {
    Controller=[[MainController alloc]init];  
  //calling viewcontroller method were we created scrollview
    [Controller moveToNextPage:1];
}


in MainController
-(void)moveToNextPage:(int )page{
    NSLog(@"%@",str);
    self.pageControl.currentPage=2;
    NSLog(@"frame: (%0f %0f; %0f %0f)",
          self.scrollViewDrug.frame.origin.x, self.scrollViewDrug.frame.origin.y,
          self.scrollViewDrug.frame.size.width, self.scrollViewDrug.frame.size.height);

    CGRect newFrame=CGRectMake(320*page,self.scrollViewDrug.frame.origin.y,self.scrollViewDrug.frame.size.width, self.scrollViewDrug.frame.size.height);
    [self.scrollViewDrug scrollRectToVisible:newFrame  animated:YES];
}
```

code link

[code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6caVk8MnBVaLTlxNWVSUHpWbWc/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: If you have a UIPageViewController, use the methods it provides : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIPageViewController/setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion: You add new viewControllers in an array an pass them to this function. Instead of doing the calculation of the scrollView yourself. If you want to stay with UIScrollView, show us the code where you initialize the scrollView, and where you set the frame.

Comment: inside viewdidload .... scrollViewDrug=[[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(2,70,307,496)];
    scrollViewDrug.showsVerticalScrollIndicator=YES;
    scrollViewDrug.scrollEnabled=YES;
    scrollViewDrug.userInteractionEnabled=YES;

Comment: Just an advice: change your message, just let the 3 lines that explain what you want, and add more code so that we better see what is happening, instead of posting a link and ask for download something. Maybe your message could help someone else in the future.

Comment: i have added entire project so i guess you can understand

Comment: Do what you want. But have a look at the thousands of questions in SO and see how it works. You add the code in your message so that others can benefit from it. You won't see a thousand people downloading your link. But if you put the code in the message, they could answer, and others would benefit from it. But if you don't want, don't do it.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating 6 View Controllers from *MainController* and then upon clicking of *Continue* button, you are again creating an object of *MainController* thinking that it will refer to the same object from where you have created those 6 object. However that is not the case, this new *MainController* is entirely new object whose components are still not initialised. That is the reason your scroll view and any other variable will be *nil* here.
**Solution**: Use *Protocol* in child controllers, create a *delegate* and make a call back to *MainController* to do the page transition.

Comment: there are plenty of examples on delegate pattern on internet. Just search for a basic tutorial and first understand the concept. Then you will be able to implement it in your project.

Comment: i dont think its an answer so please make this as comment

Comment: this is a perfectly valid answer for your question where you only asked why your scroll view is coming _nil_.

Comment: i am not forcing you to accept the answer. what i said is that i addressed you question and pointed you to the right direction. An answer can be given without code snipped or exact solution. Spend some time with delegate-protocol pattern and you will understand what i said in my solution part.